# JIT compiler unavailable after adding new modules

Tags: angular

I created a new component in my angular project. No problem so far.
Now I want to create an input area in my new components html.
For that I added `mat-form-fields` from [this examples](https://material.angular.io/components/input/examples).

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="Ex. Pizza" value="Sushi">
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

I need new imports for this component and added them to my `app.module.ts` like this:

```
import {MatInput, MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
[...]
MatInput,
MatInputModule
```

After this, I run ng build and serve the whole application to a localhost port and now app is broken with the following error:

[image]

If I delete my changes in the `app.modules.ts` and new components html, the error is gone and my app is working. Does anyone know why this error comes up?

Answer (score 1):

May be following settings in your `app.module.ts` file would work for you :)

> You don't require importing MatInput

```
...

import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],    
  imports: [
    ...
    MatInputModule    
  ],
  exports: [
    ...            
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```